# How to get out of 2 while loops and continue for loop process

Tags: php, mysql

Hello i was wondering on how can i get out of while loop while continuing the for loop, basically there is a while inside a while that's inside of a for loop.

```
<?php
for($i=1; $i <= counter($counter);$i++){
    while(){
        while(){
            if(){
               while(){
                  //if condition was met and successfully processed i want to go back to for loop. 
               }
            }else{
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Your question hasn't explained enough regarding your requirements. Just let us know at what point you want to get out from those while loops, please share your efforts if you have gone through.

Comment: you can use break; for the purpose. In your case you need to use break 3; reference - https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php

Comment: i want to get out of the inner while loop and repeat for for loop with different value for  variable $i

Answer (score 1):

Use BREAK. You can also use BREAK 1 or 2 or 3 depends on how your loop nesting.

```
<?php
for($i=1; $i <= counter($counter);$i++){
    while(){
        while(){
            if(){
               while(){
                  //if condition was met and successfully processed i want to go back to for loop. 
                   break 3;
               }
            }else{
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: it didn't work though it just stops after it met the condition inside while.

Comment: like i have said in the answer.. you can use Break 1 or Break 2 or Break 3. As per your goal, use Break 3.

Comment: you use break 3?